# How do I separate an array of objects where each object are two joined meshes that I don't want separated?

Tags: modifiers, objects

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Join a "1"-mesh and a sphere mesh
2. Make around 100 copies with two arrays
3. Apply the array modifiers and separate the objects by "Loose parts" *without "de-joining" the two meshes*
4. Apply Randomize Transform on the 100 copies
   [image: The sphere and the "1"]

When I try #4, it seems like I have also de-joined the respective "1"-meshes and sphere meshes, and they now move independently of each other: 1's are going in one direction, spheres another.

Can I somehow separate the objects of the array without "de-joining" them? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: when you separate By Loose Parts it will separate each mesh as a separate object, but maybe you could use another technic for what you want to do, like instancing, particles or geometry nodes?

Comment: you should tell us your "end goal" instead of assuming your "in-between" steps which might even not be necessary....

Comment: Because "Loose Parts" will re-separate the 1 from the sphere, I would suggest editing the mesh after joining the two but before applying the array modifiers. Use the edit to add one edge or face joining the sphere mesh and the mesh for the 1.  The "Loose Parts" will treat the whole thing as a single mesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a single edge between one vertex (each) of the '1' and 'sphere', so they are now connected.

[image]

The single edge won't show up in renderings and they are not two loose parts anymore.

[image]

Here is my example [image]